# Regex named capture group with multiple values

Tags: regex

I seem to be having a tough regex week.  Anyone that can save me from throwing my laptop out the window gets a virtual beer.  I have some data in the form of:

```
... f=something group="First Group,Group2" foo=val ...
```

where the number of groups can vary.  I need to capture each group entry to a named capture.  Based on a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424618/repeating-named-capture-groups), The difference here is that I don't have a constant to key off of within the values (i.e. ID-1-1, ID-2-2 allows me to say ID-\d+-\d+ whereas these values could be pretty much anything). I've been trying a ton of stuff, but I tend to get matches that are far too greedy, or I (often) get these 2 values:

```
First Group
First Group,Group2
```

What I need is:

```
First Group
Group2
...
```

I'm currently trying regex such as this where I'm trying to anchor to the group=" portion, and not exceed the ending ":

```
(?:(?:group=\")|(?:\"))(?<group>(?:(.+)+?)
```

Hopefully someone can make my day a lot better...

Comment: What language are you doing this in? I have a solution in PHP, but would like to try to cater to what you're using. Also, I don't think it's possible tp extract the separate values in one regex (it will always return the last result). So you need to break it in to two problems: fine the value in the quotes, then break out the comma values.

Comment: Not within a language.  It's a PCRE-compatible config file format for an application.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a simpler/built-in way within the app as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the PHP solution. Once again, regex doesn't like capturing the multiple values so we need to break it in to two searches. One extracts the group value, the next extracts each value from the group

```
$test = 'f=something group="First Group,Group2" foo=val';
$re = '/(?:group=)?\x22(?<group>(?:[^\x2C]+\x2C*)+)\x22/';
$_ = null;
if (preg_match($re,$test,$_))
  echo "Group Contents: ".$_['group']."\r\n";

$__ = null;
$re = '/(?:^|\x2C)(?<value>(?:[^\x2C]+)+)/';
if (preg_match_All($re,$_['group'],$__))
  echo "Group Values: ".print_r($__['value'],true);
```

Should be pretty easy to port in to another language, just extract the regexes out and manage them the way you normally would.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not within a programming language for this. :/

Comment: So where are you applying the regex?

Comment: it's part of a config file for an app.